# Accessing one subnet (Allnet) from another (Thomson TG712) on a local network?

Tags: networking, router, subnet

I have this situation:

[image: netdiag.png]

The Thomson Gateway TG712 is received from provider, is a phone line/DSL modem, with 4 wired LAN (RJ45) connectors, as well as wireless. It assigns to itself 192.168.1.254, and then assigns 192.168.1.* to machines connected to it via wired or wireless.

One of the LAN ports on the Thomson (which doesn't have a WAN Ethernet port, as it uses a phone connector for that purpose) is connected with the WAN RJ45 port on the Allnet router; the Thomson sees this device as 192.168.1.67 - while the Allnet sees itself as 192.168.0.1, and assigns 192.168.0.* to devices connected to it (the Allnet device is wired router only).

The machines connected to the Thomson network 192.168.1.* can ping each other, and ssh to each other (all the laptops are Ubuntus); likewise, the machines connected to the Allnet network 192.168.0.* can ping and ssh each other. My problem is - I cannot see (ping or ssh) machines on the Allnet network 192.168.0.* (Laptop D or Laptop C) from the Thomson network 192.168.1.* (from, say, Laptop A or Laptop B).

Is it possible to have machines on the Thomson network 192.168.1.* communicate with machines on the Allnet network 192.168.0.* - and if so, how? I read somewhere that what I need is "static routing", but I cannot find how to set that up on the Thomson...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it setup it will not work, your "router" is actually a router/gateway/firewall for consumer use, so many of the functions you would have to disable or change to make this work (like building static routes) are not possible.

The best way, and most efficient, could be to disable DHCP on the Allnet router, and connect a LAN port from the Thompson gateway to a LAN port of the Allnet router, making the Allnet router essentially a dumb switch, and all one subnet.

Comment: Thanks for this @acejavelin - will give this a try and report back; cheers!

Comment: Are you sure? Almost all "consumer gateways" I've used had static routes as a feature, even the most stripped down ones.

Comment: @grawity No, I don't know of that router specifically but the firewall and NATing changes that would need to be done to make these 2 networks transparent to each other are not possible in most consumer class routers. There is no stated reason to have 2 distinct subnets, so making it a single subnet would be the most efficient answer.

Comment: Thanks again - just got the time to do this, and it works - now all PCs on local network can see each other and go on the Internet (although it required a couple of reboots/dhcp renew's after changes were made). Also, as a consequence, it seems I have missed access to the Allnet router webpage (which was at 192.168.0.1), but that doesn't matter. And just to confirm, I didn't have a reason to have 2 distinct subnets, I just had it set up like in OP because I thought that is "the way" to connect two routers and have Internet. Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau You can temporarily set a computer to a 192.168.0.x IP and access the Alley router, then change its IP address to something like 192.168.1.2 or 192.168.1.254 so you can still access it, but there really isn't anything there you would need access to anymore, and if it gets redeployed again it will likely be defaulted anyway.